# Edit row in angularjs table

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following angular table with an edit button

```
<table class="tableData" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th></th>
           <th>Budget Name</th>
           <th>Year</th>
           <th>Month</th>
          <th></th>

       </tr>
   </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(ind,O) in budgetdetails">
        <tr ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">

            <td class="CX"><span>+</span></td>
            <td>{{O.budget.BudgetName}}</td>
            <td>{{O.budget.Year}}</td>
            <td>{{O.budget.Month}}</td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click='removeRow(O)' />
                <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click='EditRow(O)' /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="sub">
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="5">
                <table class="tableData" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>SubCategory</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="(indx,a) in O.budgetdetails" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
                        <td>{{a.Category}}</td>
                        <td>{{a.Subcategory}}</td>
                        <td>{{a.Amount| currency}}</td>

                    </tr>
            @*        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{Totals().Amount| currency}}</td>

        </tr>*@
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to be able to edit the data when I click on the edit button so far I have been playing with the angular controller and I have this

```
$scope.EditRow = function (item) {

    $scope.budget = item.budget;
    $scope.idBudget = item.budget.idBudget;
    $scope.BudgetName = item.budget.BudgetName;
    $scope.Year = item.budget.Year;
    $scope.Month = item.budget.Month;

     resp=BDetail.FindBudgetById(item.budget.idBudget);

};
```

The last line call a json and returns a set of data which I want to send to the page were I create the budgets for editing. Now I am not sure how to send the json to another page and the page that receives it is the View were I create the budgets and it has an IEnumerable editor to repeat the budgets details. Code is as follows

```
@model BudgetPortalMVC4.Models.budget

 @{
ViewBag.Title = "NewBudget";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

 }
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<h2>NewBudget</h2>



 @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
  <div>

  <table>

 <tr>
 <td>
     <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BudgetName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BudgetName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BudgetName)
        </div>
</td>
<td>
 <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Year)
        </div>
 <div>
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, BudgetPortalMVC4.Controllers.BudgetController.GetDropDownListForYears())
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Year)
    </div>

</td>
<td>
  <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Month)
        </div>
<div>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Month, BudgetPortalMVC4.Controllers.BudgetController.GetDropDownListForMonth())
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Month)
    </div>

</td>

</tr>

</table>
</div>

<div>

 <h3>Budget Detail</h3>

<div> <input type="button" id="addbudgetdetail" value="Add row" /></div>

 <div id="new-budgetdetail">

 @Html.EditorForMany(x => x.budgetdetails)


</div>
  <input type="submit" />


 </div>
 @section Scripts{

<script type="text/jscript">


var url = '@Url.Action("GetSubCategories", "Budget")'; // Do not hard code your url's
$(document).on('change', '.SelectedCategory', function () {
    var subCategory = $(this).closest('.item').find('.SelectedSubCategory');
    subCategory.empty();
    $.getJSON(url, { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
        if (!data) {
            return;
        }
        subCategory.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select')); // Do not give the option a value!
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            subCategory.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
        });
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#addbudgetdetail').on('click', function () {
        jQuery.get('@Url.Action("AddBudgetDetail", "Budget")').done(function (html) {
            $('#new-budgetdetail').append(html);
            $('form').data('validator', null);
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));

        });
    });

    $(".deleteRow").on("click", '', function () {
        $(this).parents("#budgetRow:first").remove();
        return false;
    });

});



 </script>

  }
 }
```

**How can I accomplish passing the json data to this view and turning the view into and updating form instead of a create form?**